# orthogonal transformations of one sheeted hyperboloid

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

I am working with one sheeted hyperboloid $S^{1,1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with equation
$$x^2+y^2-z^2=1.$$
$O(2,1)$ is defined to be a group of $Q$-orthogonal transformations preserving $S^{1,1}$.

$Q$-orthogonality means preserving of the bilinear form 
$$b[(x_1,y_1,z_1), (x_2,y_2,z_2)] = x_1x_2+y_1y_2-z_1z_2.$$

$\textbf{My question is}$: are there any references/articles which describe the general form of elements of $O(2,1)$, or decribe the finitely generated subgroups of $O(2,1)$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might have good look searching for things such as "Lorenz group in 2+1 dimensions" and so on. Also throwing the word "orthochronous" in there will probably help Google.

Comment: @AlexMeiburg thank you for your helpful comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/why-is-lorentz-group-in-3d-sl-2-r.764072/ explains that $SO(2,1) \equiv SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, and explains the conversion between them. Since you also allow non-proper transformations (those with a z inversion), an element of $O(2,1)$ is in general one of the above $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ composed with an optional z reflection.

Comment: Thank you! this isomorphism is actually what I was looking for.